# Is there a way to specify where .tmp file is created when updating an archive with 7zip command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, 7-zip

When updating an existing zip file from command line, 7zip makes a copy of the existing zip file in the same directory and renames that copy with the suffix `.tmp#` where `#` is an integer.

**Question:**

Is there a way to specify where such copies are created?

---

*Some context for whoever interested*

My use case is that I want to be able to use 7z to update large zip files frequently in OneDrive. (OneDrive being just any other cloud drive provider that can sync with local files directly.) Normally, the temp file is deleted after the main zip file is validated. Between true write errors and the update taking too long and thus the new temp file being sync'd by OneDrive, I encounter accumulation of large number of those temp files, even though the main file continues to be writable.

Being able to specify where those temp files go would have 2 benefits: 1) prevent OneDrive from sync'ing the tmep files and subsequently being unable to recognize file deletion locally; 2) I can monitor the accumulation of these tmp files in one place.

Of course, I plan to specify another location of the same drive -- so that copying is still fast and I plan to preserve the folder structure elsewhere. With that, there is no real benefit of writing the temp files to the same directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a way to specify where such copies are created?

Yes. Use the `-w` switch.

> Switch `-w` Set working directory. You can use this when you want to specify temporary folders.

Source: [7-Zip Command Line Examples - Dot Net Perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)